# SQL: How to consolidate three records into one?

Tags: sql, database, join, record, consolidation

I run a query to produce this.

```
username | userLastFirst    | email             | approver1         |department
MMickie  | Mouse, Mickie    | abc123@ships.com  | Doe, John         |HR
MMickie  | Mouse, Mickie    | abc123@ships.com  | Smith, Mike       |HR
MMickie  | Mouse, Mickie    | abc123@ships.com  | Turner, David     |HR
```

But how do I turn it into this:

```
username | userLastFirst    | email             | approver1    |approver2   |approver3    |department
MMickie  | Mouse, Mickie    | abc123@ships.com  | Doe, John    |Smith, Mike |Turner, David| HR
```

Instead of multiple rows of the same user with their approvers, I'm looking to consolidate it into one record with columns of their approvers.

Comment: Show us the query please ? Also do tag your database.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) What if there are more than three approvers?  (3) Do you know the maximum number of approvers?

Comment: What if the approvers are from different departments?

Answer (score 0):

A typical option is row_number and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    username,
    userlastfirst,
    email,
    max(case when rn = 1 then approver end) approver1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then approver end) approver2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then approver end) approver3,
    department
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by username order by approver) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by 
    username,
    userfirstlast, 
    email,
    department
```

You can adjust the `select` clause with more `max(case ... end)` expressions to handle more than 3 supervisors per user and department. The key thing is that the query returns a *fixed* set of columns.